# RxUI and Xamarin Forms: Is it possible to create Modal Pages?

Tags: xamarin.forms, reactiveui

I'm currently evaluating RxUI for future projects and so far I like what I see.
I was able to create a first test project and navigate between pages using

```
HostScreen.Router.Navigate.Execute(new  NewReleasesViewModel(HostScreen)).Subscribe();
```

Which creates a normal ContentPage with Backbutton.

I wonder how I can navigate to the ModalPage stack and display modal pages.